# Adding scroll speed to function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code.
How would I use setInterval or setTimeout to make the jump from 0px to 500px  to happen in 3000ms?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
width: 5000px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to scroll the document window to 500 pixels horizontally.</p>

<button onclick="scrollWin()">Click me to scroll horizontally!</button><br>    <br>

<script>
function scrollWin() {
window.scrollTo(500, 0);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way - divide the number of pixels to move by the amount of time to move in. Use `setInterval` to move that number of pixels in some fixed length of time `inervalTime`. Then, cancel the interval when the scroll position reaches the target.

```js
function scrollWin(target, time) {
  var currentPosition = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
  var scrollInterval = target / time;
  var intervalTime = 10;
  var intervalFunction;
  intervalFunction = setInterval(function() {
    currentPosition = currentPosition + scrollInterval * intervalTime;
    window.scrollTo(currentPosition, 0);
    if (currentPosition >= target) {
      window.clearInterval(intervalFunction);
    }
  }, intervalTime)
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to scroll the document window to 500 pixels horizontally.</p>

<button onclick="scrollWin(500, 3000)">Click me to scroll horizontally!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks ever so much for taking the time to write all that out!

Comment: I've tried to adapt it for vertical scrolling but have hit a block:
I changed 
var currentPosition = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
to
var currentPosition = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

What am I missing please?

Comment: Change `window.scrollTo(currentPosition, 0)` to `window.scrollTo(0, currentPosition)` - the parameters of `window.scrollTo()` are the X and Y coordinates of where you want to scroll to. An upvote would be much appreciated...!

Comment: Ah! of course - thanks! I've upvoted and accepted your answer